# How to display popup on 2 different pages using session state using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, popup, addeventlistener

I am displaying a popup banner using session storage and javascript add event listener. Javascript displays popup on pageload for everypages and to avoid load on every page I have used session storage.

Currently popup opens on any page per session only once.

I want following functionality.
Currently homepage is displaying popup banner and I have categories page where again when user navigates, I want to display popup on page load event in Javascript.

Comment: @atul . Any example of code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Store the state of popup in localstorage using

```
localstorage.setItem("popupState",true)
```

and use the popupState on other page

```
localstorage.getItem("popupState")
```